# SwipeRefreshLayout not showing colors at first and only shows when .setRefreshing(false) called

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I am making an android app that uses a SwipeRefreshLayout around a RelativeLayout in a fragment in a ViewPager. When I first open the app and swipe to refresh, the refresh disc shows, but it is blank with no colors.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzUeB.png

Then, the next time I swipe to refresh, there is no preview of the refresh (the disc does not come down), and when I release, it takes a second to show. I think it only runs when `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)` is called, and so it only shows for a split second.

This is my code:

```
swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.accentColor, R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            TypedValue typed_value = new TypedValue();
            getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.actionBarSize, typed_value, true);
            DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int height = dm.heightPixels;
            swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewOffset(false, -200, height / 8);
            swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                }
            });
            try {
                result = new GetReadResultTask().execute().get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (result != null && connected) {
                AlphaAnimation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
                AlphaAnimation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
                stepsTextView.setAnimation(fadeOut);
                fadeOut.setDuration(1200);
                fadeOut.setFillAfter(true);
                List<Bucket> buckets = result.getBuckets();
                for (int iii = 0; iii < buckets.size(); iii++) {
                    dumpDataSet(buckets.get(iii).getDataSet(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA));
                }
                stepsTextView.setAnimation(fadeIn);
                fadeIn.setDuration(1200);
                fadeIn.setFillAfter(true);
                series.resetData(data);
            }
            swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for this..

SwipeActivity Activity is as follows..

```
public class SwipeActivity extends Activity implements OnRefreshListener{


    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe);
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, 
                android.R.color.holo_green_light, 
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light, 
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    }


     public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

SwipeRefreshLayout is follows.

```
public class SwipeRefreshLayout extends ViewGroup {
    private static final long RETURN_TO_ORIGINAL_POSITION_TIMEOUT = 300;
    private static final float ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATION_FACTOR = 1.5f;
    private static final float DECELERATE_INTERPOLATION_FACTOR = 2f;
    private static final float PROGRESS_BAR_HEIGHT = 4;
    private static final float MAX_SWIPE_DISTANCE_FACTOR = .6f;
    private static final int REFRESH_TRIGGER_DISTANCE = 120;

    private SwipeProgressBar mProgressBar; //the thing that shows progress is going
    private View mTarget; //the content that gets pulled down
    private int mOriginalOffsetTop;
    private OnRefreshListener mListener;
    private MotionEvent mDownEvent;
    private int mFrom;
    private boolean mRefreshing = false;
    private int mTouchSlop;
    private float mDistanceToTriggerSync = -1;
    private float mPrevY;
    private int mMediumAnimationDuration;
    private float mFromPercentage = 0;
    private float mCurrPercentage = 0;
    private int mProgressBarHeight;
    private int mCurrentTargetOffsetTop;
    // Target is returning to its start offset because it was cancelled or a
    // refresh was triggered.
    private boolean mReturningToStart;
    private final DecelerateInterpolator mDecelerateInterpolator;
    private final AccelerateInterpolator mAccelerateInterpolator;
    private static final int[] LAYOUT_ATTRS = new int[] {
        android.R.attr.enabled
    };

    private final Animation mAnimateToStartPosition = new Animation() {
        @Override
        public void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            int targetTop = 0;
            if (mFrom != mOriginalOffsetTop) {
                targetTop = (mFrom + (int)((mOriginalOffsetTop - mFrom) * interpolatedTime));
            }
            int offset = targetTop - mTarget.getTop();
            final int currentTop = mTarget.getTop();
            if (offset + currentTop < 0) {
                offset = 0 - currentTop;
            }
            setTargetOffsetTopAndBottom(offset);
        }
    };

    private Animation mShrinkTrigger = new Animation() {
        @Override
        public void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            float percent = mFromPercentage + ((0 - mFromPercentage) * interpolatedTime);
            mProgressBar.setTriggerPercentage(percent);
        }
    };

    private final AnimationListener mReturnToStartPositionListener = new BaseAnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // Once the target content has returned to its start position, reset
            // the target offset to 0
            mCurrentTargetOffsetTop = 0;
        }
    };

    private final AnimationListener mShrinkAnimationListener = new BaseAnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mCurrPercentage = 0;
        }
    };

    private final Runnable mReturnToStartPosition = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mReturningToStart = true;
            animateOffsetToStartPosition(mCurrentTargetOffsetTop + getPaddingTop(),
                    mReturnToStartPositionListener);
        }

    };

    // Cancel the refresh gesture and animate everything back to its original state.
    private final Runnable mCancel = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mReturningToStart = true;
            // Timeout fired since the user last moved their finger; animate the
            // trigger to 0 and put the target back at its original position
            if (mProgressBar != null) {
                mFromPercentage = mCurrPercentage;
                mShrinkTrigger.setDuration(mMediumAnimationDuration);
                mShrinkTrigger.setAnimationListener(mShrinkAnimationListener);
                mShrinkTrigger.reset();
                mShrinkTrigger.setInterpolator(mDecelerateInterpolator);
                startAnimation(mShrinkTrigger);
            }
            animateOffsetToStartPosition(mCurrentTargetOffsetTop + getPaddingTop(),
                    mReturnToStartPositionListener);
        }

    };

    /**
     * Simple constructor to use when creating a SwipeRefreshLayout from code.
     * @param context
     */
    public SwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor that is called when inflating SwipeRefreshLayout from XML.
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public SwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();

        mMediumAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime);

        setWillNotDraw(false);
        mProgressBar = new SwipeProgressBar(this);
        final DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        mProgressBarHeight = (int) (metrics.density * PROGRESS_BAR_HEIGHT);
        mDecelerateInterpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator(DECELERATE_INTERPOLATION_FACTOR);
        mAccelerateInterpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator(ACCELERATE_INTERPOLATION_FACTOR);

        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, LAYOUT_ATTRS);
        setEnabled(a.getBoolean(0, true));
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        removeCallbacks(mCancel);
        removeCallbacks(mReturnToStartPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        removeCallbacks(mReturnToStartPosition);
        removeCallbacks(mCancel);
    }

    private void animateOffsetToStartPosition(int from, AnimationListener listener) {
        mFrom = from;
        mAnimateToStartPosition.reset();
        mAnimateToStartPosition.setDuration(mMediumAnimationDuration);
        mAnimateToStartPosition.setAnimationListener(listener);
        mAnimateToStartPosition.setInterpolator(mDecelerateInterpolator);
        mTarget.startAnimation(mAnimateToStartPosition);
    }

    /**
     * Set the listener to be notified when a refresh is triggered via the swipe
     * gesture.
     */
    public void setOnRefreshListener(SwipeActivity swipeActivity) {
        mListener = swipeActivity;
    }

    private void setTriggerPercentage(float percent) {
        if (percent == 0f) {
            // No-op. A null trigger means it's uninitialized, and setting it to zero-percent
            // means we're trying to reset state, so there's nothing to reset in this case.
            mCurrPercentage = 0;
            return;
        }
        mCurrPercentage = percent;
        mProgressBar.setTriggerPercentage(percent);
    }

    /**
     * Notify the widget that refresh state has changed. Do not call this when
     * refresh is triggered by a swipe gesture.
     *
     * @param refreshing Whether or not the view should show refresh progress.
     */
    public void setRefreshing(boolean refreshing) {
        if (mRefreshing != refreshing) {
            ensureTarget();
            mCurrPercentage = 0;
            mRefreshing = refreshing;
            if (mRefreshing) {
                mProgressBar.start();
            } else {
                mProgressBar.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the four colors used in the progress animation. The first color will
     * also be the color of the bar that grows in response to a user swipe
     * gesture.
     *
     * @param colorRes1 Color resource.
     * @param colorRes2 Color resource.
     * @param colorRes3 Color resource.
     * @param colorRes4 Color resource.
     */
    public void setColorScheme(int colorRes1, int colorRes2, int colorRes3, int colorRes4) {
        ensureTarget();
        final Resources res = getResources();
        final int color1 = res.getColor(colorRes1);
        final int color2 = res.getColor(colorRes2);
        final int color3 = res.getColor(colorRes3);
        final int color4 = res.getColor(colorRes4);
        mProgressBar.setColorScheme(color1, color2, color3,color4);
    }

    /**
     * @return Whether the SwipeRefreshWidget is actively showing refresh
     *         progress.
     */
    public boolean isRefreshing() {
        return mRefreshing;
    }

    private void ensureTarget() {
        // Don't bother getting the parent height if the parent hasn't been laid out yet.
        if (mTarget == null) {
            if (getChildCount() > 1 && !isInEditMode()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "SwipeRefreshLayout can host only one direct child");
            }
            mTarget = getChildAt(0);
            mOriginalOffsetTop = mTarget.getTop() + getPaddingTop();
        }
        if (mDistanceToTriggerSync == -1) {
            if (getParent() != null && ((View)getParent()).getHeight() > 0) {
                final DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                mDistanceToTriggerSync = (int) Math.min(
                        ((View) getParent()) .getHeight() * MAX_SWIPE_DISTANCE_FACTOR,
                                REFRESH_TRIGGER_DISTANCE * metrics.density);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        mProgressBar.draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        final int width =  getMeasuredWidth();
        final int height = getMeasuredHeight();
        mProgressBar.setBounds(0, 0, width, mProgressBarHeight);
        if (getChildCount() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        final View child = getChildAt(0);
        final int childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
        final int childTop = mCurrentTargetOffsetTop + getPaddingTop();
        final int childWidth = width - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        final int childHeight = height - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
        child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + childWidth, childTop + childHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (getChildCount() > 1 && !isInEditMode()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("SwipeRefreshLayout can host only one direct child");
        }
        if (getChildCount() > 0) {
            getChildAt(0).measure(
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                            getMeasuredWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight(),
                            MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                            getMeasuredHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom(),
                            MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return Whether it is possible for the child view of this layout to
     *         scroll up. Override this if the child view is a custom view.
     */
    public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
            if (mTarget instanceof AbsListView) {
                final AbsListView absListView = (AbsListView) mTarget;
                return absListView.getChildCount() > 0
                        && (absListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0 || absListView.getChildAt(0)
                                .getTop() < absListView.getPaddingTop());
            } else {
                return mTarget.getScrollY() > 0;
            }
        } else {
            return ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(mTarget, -1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        ensureTarget();
        boolean handled = false;
        if (mReturningToStart && ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mReturningToStart = false;
        }
        if (isEnabled() && !mReturningToStart && !canChildScrollUp()) {
            handled = onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
        return !handled ? super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) : handled;
    }

    @Override
    public void requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean b) {
        // Nope.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();
        boolean handled = false;
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mCurrPercentage = 0;
                mDownEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
                mPrevY = mDownEvent.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mDownEvent != null && !mReturningToStart) {
                    final float eventY = event.getY();
                    float yDiff = eventY - mDownEvent.getY();
                    if (yDiff > mTouchSlop) {
                        // User velocity passed min velocity; trigger a refresh
                        if (yDiff > mDistanceToTriggerSync) {
                            // User movement passed distance; trigger a refresh
                            startRefresh();
                            handled = true;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            // Just track the user's movement
                            setTriggerPercentage(
                                    mAccelerateInterpolator.getInterpolation(
                                            yDiff / mDistanceToTriggerSync));
                            float offsetTop = yDiff;
                            if (mPrevY > eventY) {
                                offsetTop = yDiff - mTouchSlop;
                            }
                            updateContentOffsetTop((int) (offsetTop));
                            if (mPrevY > eventY && (mTarget.getTop() < mTouchSlop)) {
                                // If the user puts the view back at the top, we
                                // don't need to. This shouldn't be considered
                                // cancelling the gesture as the user can restart from the top.
                                removeCallbacks(mCancel);
                            } else {
                                updatePositionTimeout();
                            }
                            mPrevY = event.getY();
                            handled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                if (mDownEvent != null) {
                    mDownEvent.recycle();
                    mDownEvent = null;
                }
                break;
        }
        return handled;
    }

    private void startRefresh() {
        removeCallbacks(mCancel);
        mReturnToStartPosition.run();
        setRefreshing(true);
        mListener.onRefresh();
    }

    private void updateContentOffsetTop(int targetTop) {
        final int currentTop = mTarget.getTop();
        if (targetTop > mDistanceToTriggerSync) {
            targetTop = (int) mDistanceToTriggerSync;
        } else if (targetTop < 0) {
            targetTop = 0;
        }
        setTargetOffsetTopAndBottom(targetTop - currentTop);
    }

    private void setTargetOffsetTopAndBottom(int offset) {
        mTarget.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);
        mCurrentTargetOffsetTop = mTarget.getTop();
    }

    private void updatePositionTimeout() {
        removeCallbacks(mCancel);
        postDelayed(mCancel, RETURN_TO_ORIGINAL_POSITION_TIMEOUT);
    }

    /**
     * Classes that wish to be notified when the swipe gesture correctly
     * triggers a refresh should implement this interface.
     */
    public interface OnRefreshListener {
        public void onRefresh();
    }

    /**
     * Simple AnimationListener to avoid having to implement unneeded methods in
     * AnimationListeners.
     */
    private class BaseAnimationListener implements AnimationListener {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    }
}
```

following is manifest file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.swiperefreshlayout"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.swiperefreshlayout.SwipeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Just copy paste all code in your project and you will get your desired output.